# Weird statusbar offset in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, view, offset, statusbar

I'm working on an app and I want to make it full screen, but when I hide the status bar I get an offset of 44px (status bar size).

With status bar the buttons are on the line:
http://i55.tinypic.com/xlbjsz.png

Then I've set in the Info.plist file "Status bar is initially hidden: YES"and I get an offset: http://i55.tinypic.com/2up3ceo.png

And when I uncheck Autoresize subviews I get this:
http://i54.tinypic.com/2h821r4.png

I've put on all xibs status bar to none, including window.xib, I don't have any ideas left, please help me.

Comment: Try making your background image / its view status-bar-length bigger?

Comment: I think the problem is not the image itself because it's resolution is 960x640, but the buttons are moved 40 px up and I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the images you uploaded it seems everything works as it should. When you hide the status bar your view will shift up the amount of pixels that the status bar was previously using to display itself.

So if the views size is 320 x 460 when the status bar is shown (the status bar has a height of 20px so if you add that up it will make it 320 x 480 the full iPhone screen size) when you hide it your view will have a new size of 320 x 480.

As you said by default your view will autoresize the views inside and when you checked it out it's only normal to get a 20px gap at the bottom of the page.

Please keep in mind that on a retina display (iPhone 4) all these sizes are doubled, so you actually get a 40px gap at the bottom.

Comment: So I should make my height of image 40 px longer?

Comment: If you are programming for retina display yes you should. More than that you should have a 320 x 480 image and another one that is twice as big (640 x 960). For example: `background.png` and `background@2x.png` - first one small, the second one twice as big. You than set the UIImage as the first one and iOS will automatically switch to the bigger one if it's running on retina display.

Comment: But my image already is 960x640 which is max size, It seems that on the second picture the image resolution is displayed good, but the buttons "Upisi" are moved 40 px up

Comment: What about your view size? Is it set to be 640 x 960? You can check that by selecting the view in interface builder and from the property inspector panel check it's size (second to last tab on the top of the panel - the one with the image of a ruler on it).

Comment: It was set to 320x460, after I changed it to 320x480 it's good :)
I don't need to set it o 960x640 and it will still be retina when it's loaded?
If I put it to 960x640 it's to big and it's hard to edit it

Comment: Sorry - I was wrong :) It needs to be 320x480 you are right, because iPhone takes care to make it double the size for retina display.

Comment: Thanks man :)
Do I need to set it to 960x640 to be retina? It's hard to edit it when I set the view to that size, it's to big...

Comment: No! Never think sizes in retina way. The only thing that should be in retina size should be your images. All the views and coordinates etc should be in normal sizes (320 x 480). iPhone takes care of translating those to the bigger size of retina display.